# PHP Mongo Aggregation only returns _id

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to return a collection of messages grouped by in_reply_to field, I have this code:

```
$result = $this->db->Message->aggregate(
            array(
                array(
                    '$project' => array('message' => 1, 'in_reply_to'=> 1, 'to_user' => 1, 'from_user' => 1)
                ),
                array(
                    '$group' => array('_id' => '$in_reply_to'),
                ),
            )
        );
        print_r($result);exit;
```

the result is:

```
Array ( 
    [result] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [_id] => MongoId Object ( 
                [$id] => 53a03d43b3f7e236470041a8 
            ) 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [_id] => MongoId Object ( 
                [$id] => 53a03cbdb3f7e2e8350041bb
            ) 
        ) 
   ) 
   [ok] => 1 
)
```

Ideally I'd like the entire Message object, but I did think that $project would be used to specify returns fields, even so, I dont get the fields I'm specifying.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If "in_reply_to" does not have a direct relation to an original document then you will not be able to do this. You can look at [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) as an option to get the "first" matching document to each grouping.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I do an update to the first message to set its in_reply_to to its own _id. Not cute but its one cleaner way of creating conversations of messages.

Comment: Sounds like you want the "thread" of messages that all have the same in reply to. Some sample data here would help people understand.

Comment: Sure, heres the current query and and mongo export: http://codeshare.io/wPObP

Comment: So what is it that you want? I see two sets of 4 messages with the same "in_reply_to". Do you just want those messages returned "attached" to the "in_reply_to" value?

Comment: 2 collections of 4 messages (as a collection itself)

Comment: Got it. A few moments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get all the messages in the thread you basically want to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

```
$result = $this->db->Message->aggregate(
    array(
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$in_reply_to',
                'messages' => array(
                    '$push' => array(
                        '_id' => '$_id',
                        'message' => '$message',
                        'to_user' => '$to_user',
                        'from_user' =>'$from_user'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

MongoDB 2.6 you have the `$$ROOT` variable that shortens this:

```
$result = $this->db->Message->aggregate(
    array(
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$in_reply_to',
                'messages' => array(
                    '$push' => '$$ROOT'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

So that puts all of the related messages inside the "messages" array tied to that key.

Just as side note, while you can do this you may as well just sort the results by your "in_reply_to" field and process them that way looking for changes in the value to indicate a new thread.

Sorting with a find would be the fastest way to process, even if it does not conveniently put everything right under the one key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get additional fields beside `_id` field, when using $group operator, you need to include them using some of the available accummulators like $first or $last. You can see the full list on the MongoDB [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) documentation page.

The query will look like this:

```
$result = $this->db->Message->aggregate(
    array(
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                'message' => 1, 
                'in_reply_to'=> 1, 
                'to_user' => 1, 
                'from_user' => 1
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$in_reply_to',
                'message' => array('$first' => '$message'),
                'to_user' => ('$first' => '$to_user'),
                'from_user' => ('$first' => '$from_user')
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

If the `message`, `to_user` and `from_user` values are same in all documents using `$last` instead of `$first` `$last` will produce the same results.

Comment: That just returns: [
{
_id: {
$id: "53a03d43b3f7e236470041a8"
},
message: "message",
to_user: "to_user",
from_user: "from_user"
},
{
_id: {
$id: "53a03cbdb3f7e2e8350041bb"
},
message: "message",
to_user: "to_user",
from_user: "from_user"
}
],
1
],

Comment: @azz0r - sorry it was late and I forgot to add `$` when writing field names in the query. Now it's fixed :)